# Multiple processes of reading and modifying transaction on the same table

Tags: sql, database, multithreading, concurrency

I think this is typical question for how modern database handle the concurrency issue.
Say we have a process P1 of modifying db transaction(insert or delete) for the table. Transaction would begin -- sql -- commit. Then during the course before P1 commits the transaction, what if now we have another process P2 comes in to have read transaction for the table? What'll happen? Can P2 still read the table?

Either the table will be locked and P2 won't be able to read until P1 finishes, Or, P2 will read the table, reading off the introduced change by P1?

Comment: Consider reading about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: Modern databases don't lock the whole table if you insert, update or delete rows. They only lock the rows in question - P2 won't see the changed data until P1 commits. See e.g. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html)

Comment: I consider this question too broad.  A question on how locking and transactional semantics works across all databases does not seem suitable for Stack Overflow.  You can start with the documentation on whatever database you are using.  Or perhaps the Wikipedia pages on ACID properties, database transactions, and similar pages.

Comment: Thanks! The reading of that wiki page has already solved all my confusion thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on database implementation details and timing. In general, until P1 is committed, its results are not valid, so it will not have exclusively locked the table for reading. P2 will most likely not encounter any lock and read the old data.

I'm saying "most likely" because this also depends on configured isolation levels in the database. No serious production database survives for long when configured to be "serializable", implying perfect isolation between transaction. So, depending on the situation, a "phantom read" or other weird things may occur. This is the trade-off between locking continuously or accepting a potential weirdness every now and then.

As @Smutje mentioned in the comment, do consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) in full, it's mandatory knowledge once you contemplate questions like this.